# sas - how to match current row with previous and then assign a value in the another column

Tags: sql, sas

What I have is the following data:

```
data haveb1;
infile cards truncover expandtabs;
input MC $ ET $ Date : date9. Time : hhmmss5. TPMC $ PXMC $ Site $ Dia MV;
format date date9. time hhmm5.;
cards;
US0001 CRE 29MAY13 0:00 7611 HTELI1124P 1 . 2734440.00000
US0001 CRE 31JAN14 0:00 7402 HTELI1015P 2 . 2735017.00000
US000323 Removal 31OCT12 0:00 7416 HTELI1079P 3 . 1346049.00000
US000323 Inst 11JAN13 0:00 7408 HTELI1034P 3 . 1346049.00000
US000323 Removal 24MAY14 0:00 7408 HTELI1034P 3 . 1812537.00000
US000328 CRE 03FEB13 0:00 7209 HTELI1115P 3 . 2040610.00000
US000328 CRE 18JUL14 0:00 7218 HTELI1152P 3 . 2134438.00000
US000328 Inst 15FEB15 0:00 7508 HTELI1098P 3 . 2180863.00000
US000328 CRE 21MAY15 0:00 7212 HTELI1098P 3 . 2232830.00000
US000328 CRE 01OCT15 0:00 7111 HTELI1215P 2 . 2232830.00000
US000329 Removal 21MAR14 0:00 7110 HTELI1148P 2 . 2130325.00000
US000329 CRE 18SEP14 0:00 7517 HTELI1211P 3 . 2130325.00000
US000331 CRE 02SEP13 0:00 7207 HTELI020 2 . 2059478.00000
US000331 Removal 17JUN15 0:00 7207 HTELI020 2 . 2689105.00000
US000331 Inst 19APR16 0:00 7114 HTELI1147P 3 . 2689105.00000
US000334 Inst 26JUN13 0:00 7512 HTELI1023P 2 . 2535592.00000
US000334 CRE 04JUL14 0:00 7217 HTELI1145P 2 . 2815903.00000
;
run;
```

And what I want to do is to 'count' how many times MC has been changed from one TPMC to another. So that final output should look like:

```
MC  ET  Date    Time    TPMC    Change  PXMC    Site    Dia MV
US0001  CRE 29May2013   0:00    7611    0   HTELI112    1       2734440
US0001  CRE 31Jan2014   0:00    7402    1   HTELI101    2       2735017
US000323    Removal 31Oct2012   0:00    7416    0   HTELI107    3       1346049
US000323    Inst    11Jan2013   0:00    7408    1   HTELI103    3       1346049
US000323    Removal 24May2014   0:00    7408    0   HTELI103    3       1812537
US000328    CRE 03Feb2013   0:00    7209    1   HTELI111    3       2040610
US000328    CRE 18Jul2014   0:00    7218    1   HTELI115    3       2134438
US000328    Inst    15Feb2015   0:00    7508    1   HTELI109    3       2180863
US000328    CRE 21May2015   0:00    7212    1   HTELI109    3       2232830
US000328    CRE 01Oct2015   0:00    7111    1   HTELI121    2       2232830
US000329    Removal 21Mar2014   0:00    7110    0   HTELI114    2       2130325
US000329    CRE 18Sep2014   0:00    7517    1   HTELI121    3       2130325
US000331    CRE 02Sep2013   0:00    7207    0   HTELI020    2       2059478
US000331    Removal 17Jun2015   0:00    7207    0   HTELI020    2       2689105
US000331    Inst    19Apr2016   0:00    7114    1   HTELI114    3       2689105
US000334    Inst    26Jun2013   0:00    7512    0   HTELI102    2       2535592
US000334    CRE 04Jul2014   0:00    7217    1   HTELI114    2       2815903
```

basically what is happening here is that, first row of 'Change' column is always 0 and then if TPMC in the current row is not the same as in the previous row, 1 appears in 'Change' column, otherwise 0 appears.

**how can it be done?**

When I run the code as what **Chris J** (in answer) wrote, I get following result, which is not meeting the requirement, unfortunately:

```
proc sort data=haveb1 ;
  by MC Date Time ;
run ;

data want ;
  set haveb1 ;
  by MC Date Time TPMC notsorted ;
  if first.MC then Change = 0 ;
  else
  if first.TPMC then Change + 1 ;
run ;
```

RESULT:

```
US0001  Lath    02JAN13 19:24               876 2660403.00000   1   0
US0001  CRE 29MAY13 0:00    7611    HTELI1124P  1   .   2734440.00000   1   0
US0001  CRE 31JAN14 0:00    7402    HTELI1015P  2   .   2735017.00000   1   0
US0001  Lath    12JAN15 7:00                .   2900334.00000   1   0
US000323    Lath    13OCT12 19:37               852.2   1332753.00000   1   0
US000323    WI  25OCT12 0:00                .   1342148.00000   1   0
US000323    Remov   31OCT12 0:00    7416    HTELI1079P  3   .   1346049.00000   1   0
US000323    Lath    31OCT12 14:03               890.5   1346049.00000   1   0
US000323    Installation    11JAN13 0:00    7408    HTELI1034P  3   .   1346049.00000   1   0
US000323    Lath    16.marras.13    19:52               888.7   1417443.00000   1   0
US000323    Lath    12OCT13 13:49               886.7   1606899.00000   1   0
US000323    Lath    12OCT13 14:17               886.7   1606899.00000   1   0
US000323    Remov   24MAY14 0:00    7408    HTELI1034P  3   .   1812537.00000   1   0
US000328    Meas    17OCT12 16:11               .   1941116.00000   .   0
US000328    Meas    17OCT12 16:11               852.2   1941116.00000   .   1
US000328    Meas    18OCT12 10:53               849.8   1943064.00000   .   0
US000328    Meas    18OCT12 10:53               849.8   1942090.00000   .   1
US000328    Meas    18OCT12 10:53               852.1   1943064.00000   .   2
US000328    Meas    18OCT12 10:53               852.1   1942090.00000   .   3
US000328    Meas    20OCT12 10:17               849.7   1944562.00000   .   0
US000328    Meas    20OCT12 10:17               851.9   1944562.00000   .   1
```

Comment: In desired results, shouldn't the first *US000328* be a 0?

Comment: Actually, above data is just a subset of a larger one. What I want first row should be zero and whenever there are a change of TPMC from subsequent row (it could be after a null cell as well), the count should start. And if two consecutive rows have same TMPC, count should not increase, it should increase only when there is a change. Thanks.

Comment: Again the rows for *MC=US000328* should then begin at 0 and then increase right? Right now in your desired output, for this MC grouping, they are all ones as each row changes TPMC. Please update.

Comment: Yes MC=US000328 should at 0. And because there is NULL TPMC, so  Change should be 0. Further, suppose TPMC changes to 7101, the change=1 and it will continue to be 1, even if we have TPMC=7101 in the next row. but if TPMC in some row changes to 7102, then Change=2. and so forth.

Comment: Your second lot of example data has missing `TPMC` values... as such they count as a change. Either retain the non-missing TPMC values where appropriate, or amend my code to detect null values.

Comment: may be you can modify your answer below. it might help other sas users as well. thanks Chris.

Comment: The simple addition of a `not missing(...)` in the appropriate place would solve your issue (assuming your sample data is representative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two `proc sql` runs with first initial `data` step (which can also be handled during import of data). Had SAS allowed CTEs like RDMS's do, this can be handled in one run. Of course you can still embed first query into every *want1* in second query for one `proc sql`.

Steps

1. Before anything, add a primary *ID* column using row number `_N_` (customary in most SQL engine database tables) used for tie breakers for same dated records:

   ```
   data haveb1;
       set haveb1;    
       id = _N_;       
   run;
   ```
2. First SQL uses a correlated aggregate subquery to return counts by ordered *Date* for each *MC* group with the condition of *TMPC* maintaining a non-zero length value. Please note: TMPC must be as a character for below to work.
3. Second SQL corrects the new *Change* column to increase by one after those tied values. A `CASE` logic statement is used to clean up the missing *TPMC* values.

**SAS** Code

```
proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE want1 AS

    SELECT h.MC, h.ET, h.Date, h.Time, 

         (SELECT Count(*) FROM haveb1 sub
          WHERE sub.MC = h.MC AND sub.TPMC ne h.TPMC AND LENGTH(sub.TPMC) > 1
          AND (sub.Date < h.Date OR sub.Date = h.Date AND sub.id < h.id )) AS Change, 

         h.TPMC, h.PXMC, h.Site, h.Dia, h.MV
    FROM haveb1 h;
quit;

proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE want2 AS

    SELECT w.MC, w.ET, w.Date, w.Time,  
         CASE WHEN LENGTH(w.TPMC) > 1 
              THEN (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.MC, t.Change FROM want1 t) sub
                    WHERE sub.MC = w.MC AND sub.Change < w.Change)  
              ELSE 0 
         END AS Change,     

         w.TPMC, w.PXMC, w.Site, w.Dia, w.MV
    FROM want1 w;
quit;
```

[image: SAS Proc SQL Output]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Parfait . Only one issue here, it consumes a lot time for my full dataset. May be you can look into something which reduces the time for processing. :)

Comment: How large is your dataset? One optimization option is to convert subqueries to derived tables or joined views but your specific task is too nuanced that for correlation to work it must be inline to `SELECT` clause. Possibly break up the dataset into smaller ones and then stack them back with `set` command.

Comment: it is about 1.6 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `first.` and the `notsorted` option :

```
proc sort data=haveb1 ;
  by MC Date Time ;
run ;

data want ;
  set haveb1 ;
  by MC Date Time TPMC notsorted ;
  if first.MC then Change = 0 ;
  else
  if first.TPMC then Change + 1 ;
run ;
```

Comment: sorry unfortunately this does not give desired result. :( thanks anyways.

Comment: although it works for small subset as above, it fails for larger data.